# what is the purpose of this javascript code structure?

Tags: javascript

What is the purpose of this javascript code structure?:

```
var GivenArrayOfJobs = () => {
    var selectedJob: WorkerModels.JobDetailsResponseModel = {
        JobId: "25c63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317",
        WorkerId: "56e63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317"
    };
    return selectedJob;
}
```

Specifically, I'm not sure what the following syntax indicates or its advantage over a more traditional js implementation:

```
var GivenArrayOfJobs = () => {
```

Comment: `() => {} ≡ function(){}.bind(this)`

Comment: This is ES6/2015 syntax. Learn it. Love it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Comment: This part doesn't look like legal syntax: `var selectedJob: WorkerModels.JobDetailsResponseModel = {...}` unless it's something new I've never seen before.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax is called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and are new in ES2015 specification.

One obvious advantage is that there is slightly less code to write.

Also, arrow functions are lexically scoped and so if you use `this` inside and arrow function it is bound to the lexical container.  In some scenarios this reduces the need to explicitly bind the context (e.g. `.bind(this)`).

In your example, there is not much difference (in scoping) because `this` is not used, but the syntax is (subjectively) a bit nicer.

Comment: In this particular example, what is the advantage of the arrow function over a basic js variable like this:

var GivenArrayOfJobs = selectedJob.WorkerModels.JobDetailsResponseModel = {
 JobId: "25c63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317",
        WorkerId: "56e63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317"
};

Answer (score 1):

It is Ecmascript 6 [`arrow function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It is very similar to `anonymous function`s except that it will bind its lexical scope into it automatically. And that bound scope cannot be modified via `call`/`apply` or any further `.bind(obj)`

Arrow function implementation:

```
var GivenArrayOfJobs = () => {
    selectedJob.WorkerModels.JobDetailsResponseModel = {
        JobId: "25c63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317",
        WorkerId: "56e63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317"
    };
    return selectedJob;
}
```

Anonymous function implementation:

```
var GivenArrayOfJobs = function(){
    selectedJob.WorkerModels.JobDetailsResponseModel = {
        JobId: "25c63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317",
        WorkerId: "56e63b12-9e37-4be0-a8af-4cf237766317"
    };
    return selectedJob;
}.bind(this);
```